# i Have written this membership class, how can i create a method to find a specific ID given to a member?

Tags: java

Guys this is my membership class so far, i am struggling to create a method that finds the full members details that i have given just using a uniqueId finder. Please help.

```
public class Membership {

    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private int memberId;
    private String listOfMembers;
    private int uniqueId;
    private long phoneNumber;



    public Membership(String FirstName, String LastName, int uniqueId,
    long phoneNumber)
    {


       this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
       this.FirstName = FirstName;
       this.LastName = LastName;
       this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


    public String getMember()
    {
        return FirstName + LastName;
    }
    public String getlistOfMembers()
    {
        return (FirstName + LastName);
    }
    public int getId()
    {
      return uniqueId;
    }

    public void MemberId (int Id)
    {
        System.out.println("Id" + Id);
    }

    public String getMemberDetails ()
    {
        System.out.println("Member Id: " + uniqueId);
        System.out.println("first name:  " + FirstName);
        System.out.println("LastName:  " + LastName);
        System.out.println("Member phone number:  " + phoneNumber);
        return listOfMembers;
    }


}
```

This is what i have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on Hovercraft's answer with an example.

You have your class handling all the members, very basic implementation of it.

```
public class Membership {
    private final Map<Integer, Member> members = new HashMap<>();

    public void addMember (Integer uniqueId, Member member) {
        members.put (uniqueId, member);
    }

    public void getMember (Integer uniqueId) {
        return members.get (uniqueId);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you have the `Member`s themselves like this, more fields can be added as you want them.

```
public class Member {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Member (String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName () {
        return firstName;
    }

    ...
}
```

This is a very basic, but strong, feature in OOP to use.

Again see Hovercraft's answer as it provides all the details. If they were to edit/remove I will update this one.

**Map vs List**

One minor thing is I'd vote against using an `ArrayList<E>` to store the `Member`s. If you add to the implementation that you can remove users the `uniqueId` will shift from user to user. Instead I would be for making sure that you are not adding to an existing user.

If you want to keep it simple and just get going, an `ArrayList<E>` works, do know the problem you might get in the feature, an `uniqueId` is not necessarily tied to a `Member`.

*"I am quite new to java and have never come across "map" can you please explain what it is?"*

"An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value." - From: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Instead of working with direct indexes as you do in an `Array`:

- arr[5]; // here you get the value at index position 5.

Or like a `List`:

- list.get(5); // here you get the fifth element, it can be stored (almost) anywhere in the memory, before or after 4, doesn't matter, as 4 knows where 5 is.

And for a `Map`:

- map.get(5); // you get the object stored at 5, there might not be a 3 or 4 in the `Map`. You can store any `Object`s as anything. A `String` is another example of a common `key`.

Answer (score 2):

Issues:

- You've got user interface code where it doesn't belong. I would remove all `System.out.println` statements from this class and instead leave it in a UI class or main method (if very simple).
- In particular, getter methods should return field values, and should not have `System.out.println` statements
- I'm not sure why this class has a `listOfMembers` field, or why it's just a String. You look to be trying to combine Member and Membership together in one single class -- Don't do this.
- I'd name this class `Member` since it holds information for just a single Member.
- If I needed a Membership class, it would instead hold an `ArrayList<Member>`
- And it would have a `public Member getMember(int id)` method that would return the item in the list above that shares the id passed into the method. A simple for loop that iterated through the list, comparing id's would suffice.

Comment: it is supposed to be a list of members.

Comment: @codercc: Then you're doing it wrong. Please see edits. Don't try to combine Member with Membership. This class should not have first name, last name, or id fields, or any other Member fields.

Comment: thanyou, Why not have any of those fields?

Comment: @codercc: why should you have those fields? Seriously. This is supposed to hold a **bunch** of Members. Does having those fields make any sense?

Comment: I thought that is how you inputted a new member?

Comment: @codercc, I added an example based on Hovercraft's answer. Make sure you understand what he wrote in it.

Comment: @Emz: I didn't post code for a reason. codercc would be far better off trying to write his own code, but 1+ for the efforts.

Comment: I understand your point, I also agree to some extent with it, which is why I didn't supply all features necessary. However I thought an example to see it in "reality" would be very helpful, even a stub one.

Comment: @codercc: 1) It's kind of like an ArrayList, but you look items up using a String (or other object) and not an int. 2) The answer to your question above is something you could easily look it up, and probably *should* look up. 3) I don't think that you need to use a Map here as it may be a bit of over-kill for your simple app.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i have just looked at map and i think it may work well with this application.

Comment: @codercc: You're welcome. Please be sure to up-vote all the answers to this question that helped you. If it were my question, I'd give up-votes to all 3 of the answers, since they all appear "helpful", and I would "accept" the one that helped the most.

Comment: How do you up vote? sorry i am new to this stackoverflow. I find all this very useful thank you.

Comment: @codercc, next to where you accept the answer there are two arrows, between them on this post it says "2", which is the score of this post. You can press the up-/down-arrow, up means it was helpful to you, down... not so much.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am a student on programming and i am really enjoying learning how to code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Map and use id as key of Map and store object of Membership as Value,thereby easy to retrieve and store also.

Something similar to this,

```
 Map<Integer,Membership> map = new HashMap<Integer,Membership>();
    Membership m = new Membership("First", "LastName", 1,1234567890);
    map.put(m.getId(), m);
```

To get member by id,

```
 System.out.println(map.get(id).getMemberDetails());
```

Comment: I am quite new to java and have never come across "map" can you please explain what it is?

Comment: Map is a key-value pair data structure,where key is unique.So this data structure will be more suitable in your case.

To read more about Map read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html